# couldn't set registry for file association

Tags: registry, inno-setup, libvlc, file-association

I am trying to associate .mpg video file to my video player. but it will get associated only when i disabled the windows media player. It won't get associated when the Windows media player is enabled. Please help me in this regard. Thank you.

/*This is my inno script code*/

```
[setup]
ChangesAssociations=yes


 [registry]
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\VideoPlayer.AssocFile.mpg"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "MPEG video file"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\VideoPlayer.AssocFile.mpg\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName},0"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\VideoPlayer.AssocFile.mpg\Shell\Open"; ValueName: Icon; ValueType: String; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\VideoPlayer.AssocFile.mpg\Shell\Open\Command"; ValueType: String; ValueData: """{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletekey
    Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Classes\.mpg"; ValueType: String; ValueData: "VideoPlayer.AssocFile.mpg"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty;
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root key that you used ? File associations are stored in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` as far as I know. About "disabling" the Windows Media Player, just a guess; there might be a service, which keeps the association set unless you disable it.

Comment: Maybe media player associate the files at start?

Comment: @TLama: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a virtual key that represents keys from `Software\Classes` from both `HKLM` and `HKCU`.  So the script in the question is perfectly fine.  (Except that it is generally recommended to *not* remove the extension value on uninstall.)

Answer (score 1):

User associations "win" over machine associations, so if the user has explicitly requested that Media Player be used to open these files in the past then it will remain associated despite the action of an installer.  This is correct behaviour; the user's preferences should always win.  Try it on a fresh install (use a VM) or create a brand new user account to test it under, and you should find it working as expected.  You can direct users affected by this to use Open With or the Default Programs control panel to change their selection, but you should not attempt to do this programmatically.

The script in the question shows the "classic" method for file associations (Win98 era), which is still supported, but there are a few extra values you should probably set, especially when trying to associate with a common file type such as `.mpg`.  (At least `OpenWithProgIds` -- in fact you may wish to set only this if you want your app to be an option but not the default one.)

The best way to learn about the options is to [read the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148.aspx).  Once you know what registry values you want to set for your use-case, if you have any trouble translating that to Inno script please feel free to ask another question with the specifics.